# SetData method removes event handlers of ckeditor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor

I have such code

```
CKEDITOR.instances.myInstance.document.on('keyup', function(event) {
            if(event.keyCode == 13)
            {
                $('linkId').click();
            }
        }
```

Event handler for `$('linkId).click()` has this logic `CKEDITOR.instances.myInstance.sedData('')`. It works just one times. If I comment calling setData('') keyup event fires many times. I don't understand why. It looks like setData() removes event handlers. Does anybody know why it happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently reported it to the bug tracker http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10365 but although they don't know why it happens they have closed it as invalid saying that you must change your code for CKEditor 4 (and of course that's not documented at all anywhere and even they are suffering this problem)

The ticket includes a sample with a workaround.

Comment: So, did you find solution? How to avoid such behaviour?

Comment: I used my own solution but as I said the ticket includes a modified testcase with a workaround.

Comment: Kuba closed that ticket too early, but I just checked that in v3 that listener is also detached by browser on `setData`, so your ticket is indeed invalid. I tested this on FF (latest and 3.6) and Chrome by  attaching `keyup` listener on `contentDom`.

Comment: Interesting, because I tested with 3.6 and it worked fine (after all I know that my plugins work correctly with 3.6) so I had to find out the difference between 3.6 and 4. I've tested again the modified API sample in 3.6 and it works fine, both click and keyup events.

Answer (score 0):

```
CKEDITOR.instances.myInstance.on('contentDom', function () {
    CKEDITOR.instances.myInstance.editable().attachListener(CKEDITOR.instances.myInstance.document, 'keyup', function (event) {
        if (event.data.$.keyCode == 13) {
            alert("do your work!");
        }
    });
});
```